# Rotate is stuck at where my mouse pointer is

Tags: css

I want to make an animation in CSS where in ihover on a element, it should flip 360 degree and show its other side.

I used `animation: sparkred linear .5s;` and then used `@keyframes` to animate it at 0% and 100% but the animation got stuck at the point where mouse is hovered.
I also tried the `transition: transform` way (it is commented in the fiddle), but worked almost the same.
Here is the complete CSS:

```
html, body{ height: 100%;}
.box1{width: 25%; float: left; height: 100%; }
.blue{ background-color: #0f09cc;}
.red{ background-color: #cc0000;<!-- transform: rotateX(0deg); transition: transform 1.5s;--> }
.red:hover{ animation: sparkred linear .5s; <!--  transform: rotateX(270deg); -moz-transform: rotateX(270deg); -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg); --> }
.green{ background-color: #00cc00;}
.purple{ background-color: #cc00cc;}

@keyframes sparkred{
0%{transform: rotateX(0deg)}
100%{transform: rotateX(360deg)}
}
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/npb9M/

Comment: is "truck" ? are you sure?

Comment: thanks, @secretformula, but could you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The "getting stuck" issue might have to do with the rotating item itself having the `:hover`. The element's size changes, so the hover hitbox changes as well.

You can have an inner element that rotates, while having the same hover hitbox.

In this fiddle I've got something working; you might be able to use this as an example.

**http://jsfiddle.net/npb9M/1/**